# NSFileManager ubiquityIdentityToken App crashes unexpectedly (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsfilemanager

Inside the code when trying to check whether `ubiquityIdentityToken` nil or not my app accidentally crashes but sometimes it works. I am confused with this issue. Your help is welcome

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try running the app on simulator with thread sanitiser enabled (Edit Scheme -> Run/Debug -> Diagnostics -> Thread sanitiser -> Pause on issues). Maybe there is an occasional race condition that causes this crash.

Comment: Found the bug! Was releasing it somewhere else inside the code